# Must load modules before making target

Tags: makefile

I need to ensure that certain modules are loaded for the build process to proceed. I need one Makefile that can make one or several programs (submodel).

What I have currently:

```
all : submodel_01 submodel_02 submodel_03

check-modules: load_modules.sh
    @if [ -z "${MODULES_LOADED}" ]; then \
        echo "Please run"; \
        echo "source $<"; \
        echo "first."; \
        exit 1; \
    fi

.PHONY: check-modules

load_modules.sh:
    @echo "export MODULES_LOADED=yes" > $@
    @echo "module load intel-compiler" >> $@
    @echo "module load openmpi" >> $@

submodel_01: check-modules
    <command to make submodel_01>

submodel_02: check-modules
    <command to make submodel_02>

submodel_03: check-modules
    <command to make submodel_03>
```

This kinda works, but it's not very elegant. I'd much rather have make load the modules itself, then run a child make process where the modules are loaded.

I want to ensure though that the original intended target is preserved. So if I run just `make`, then it should make all three submodels, but if I specify a specific target, it should only make that one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not MPI expert, and I was not able to test.

I believe that for the `module load` command to work, it has to be executed by the parent process (before running Makefile), or in the same shell that will need the environment.

Given that each separate action in running in a separate shell, I think that the following will NOT work - the setting will not pass to the 2nd command. (Suggest you give it a try, just in case.)

```
submodel_01:
    source load_modules.sh
    <command that depends on modules>
```

However, this should work

```
submodel_01:
    source load_modules.sh ; <commands that depends on modules.sh>
```

You can even include the 'guard' in load_modules.sh to prevent repeated sourcing by changing load_modules.sh to:

```
if [ ! "$MODULES_LOADED" ] ; then
   module load intel-compiler"
   module load openmpi
   export MODULES_LOADED=yes"
fi
```